# Variable seems to change its type in one line without reason. AnyLogic SelectOutput not working correctly types not working correctly

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I have a problem in my SelectOutput element. The input type is "Customer", and in the Java code this is reflected correctly with the "agent" function parameter having type "Customer". However, when I access this "agent" parameter it is no longer a "Customer" type, but "StockItem" - another one of my agent types which isn't involved in this flow chart.

Error message in comment in code below:

```
  private boolean _hasBought_condition_xjal( final com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.SelectOutput<Customer> self, Customer agent ) {
    boolean _value;
    _value = (Customer)(agent).buyingItem!=null; // <-- Error here "Description: Cannot cast from StockItem to Customer. Location: CW2_shop_2/Shop/hasBought - SelectOutput"
    return _value;
  }
```

It makes even less sense because the exact same cast works in the "On Enter" field below it, here is the setup of the SelectOutput:
[image]
I need to access a parameter of the Customer agent accessing it with "agent.buyingItem" throws an error that "type StockItem does not have parameter buyingItem", which lead me to try and cast it first as you see above. 
I've already tried restarting AnyLogic and rebuilding.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
After discovering that I didn't need the type casting to Customer and removing it, I still find that the values between "Condition" and "onEnter" are different. I added lots of debug lines and you can see the output in the image below. The values of "agent.buyingItem!=null" seem to change. "notNull: true" is printed, but then the agent leaves through false no matter the value.

buyingItem is a variable of type StockItem, which is a blank agent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are wrong.

`(Customer)(agent).buyingItem` is getting `buyingItem` (presumably of type StockItem) and then trying to cast *that* to `Customer`.

You should be doing

`((Customer) agent).buyingItem`

Your on-enter code is correct, hence the different outputs.

Comment: Thanks! you're right. However I've found that I don't need those typecasts, and even when I remove them the values between onEnter and condition are still different. I've added an edit with an image to the original post to show you what I mean.

Comment: Okay so I fixed the problem. agent.buyingItem is set to be notnull in the onExit of a delay block immediately before this selectOutput. After moving this to the OnAtExit of the delay block it works fine. So I'm guessing it hadn't updated yet when the condition was evaluated, but was when the onExit(True) was evaluated or something.

Answer (score 0):

in the condition you should do the following

```
agent.buyingItem!=null
```

your agent is already a customer so no need to cast it to a customer like you are trying to do and doing (agent) instead of agent does not work and might have a different meaning.